# Are there any examples of non-residential EN54 fire alarm systems that use WIFI for communication?

Tags: wifi, embedded-systems, smart-device

I am undertaking a research project on behalf of a client looking at fire alarm / smoke detection systems aimed at a non-domestic, non-residential market; looking at around 200+ odd devices that may work on the same system.

Specifically, the client wants big fire alarm systems which communicate over WiFi and comply with [EN54](https://www.fia.uk.com/resources/british-standards/bs-en-54-series-fire-detection-alarm-systems.html) ([more](http://www.sourceen54.eu/en-54-certification.html)) ([more](https://uk.advancedco.com/media/155792/680_212_01__Application_Note___EN54_13_Overview.pdfhttps://uk.advancedco.com/media/155792/680_212_01__Application_Note___EN54_13_Overview.pdf)) ([more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EN_54)).

I've done some searching and found residential ones, i.e., Google Nest and Alexa based ones, but I've found it hard to find any commercial, big-fire alarm systems that are EN54-compliant and operate via WiFi.

Is anyone aware and can recommend such a system?

I've looked on Alibaba, Google and some big commercial suppliers and sent out emails. I hope someone can indeed recommend, or is knowledgeable of big systems that comply with EN54 and use WiFi for communication.

Comment: I'm sure the client's insurance company would turn 17 shades of purple at the prospect of relying on the eminently hackable WiFi infrastructure your client proposed you investigate. Sure enough, about 30 minutes of search revealed no such device.